# Does phonegap for android supports https ajax requests?

Tags: android, ajax, ssl, https, cordova

I am developing a phonegap application on Android which uses ajax requests to the server with https protocol. The SSL certificate that the server uses now is trusted and verified ( you can check it if you want to: https://www.korebe.com/Android/Bilgi ) but result of the xmlhttp requests is always blank due to https connection.

Same version of the on http is works fine but I want to connect through https.

What could be reason behind this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean that you need to display this into mobile screen ? {"ucret_sms":"0,50 TL","ucret_mms":"1 TL","ucret_call":"1 TL","musteri_hizmetleri":"0530 491 2426"}

Comment: yes but using the xmlhttp and synchronized ajax call

Comment: are you aware with webservices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your certificate. When I try to connect to other SSL sites the request works fine, but when I try to connect to your it chokes.

When I visit your site in the browser, it does show a green lock and everything appears fine, but then whenI view the certificate information I see this.

[image]

I am not sure what the problem is, but I have read that the combination of PhoneGap and the Android Emulator do not handle cert errors well.

I really suspect that the issue is your cert.

Just for fun, I tried my test on a real device too (Nexus One with Android 2.3) and it also failed there.

Comment: I just realize the thing is that if you open the https://www.korebe.com/Android/Bilgi from your browser at the first time you can see the certificate is signed by RapidSSL (green flag)

But if you open the https://www.korebe.com/ and after you pass that URL certificate seems unauthorized (red flag)